# OpenVPN do not change my DNS on windows

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, openvpn

I set up openvpn server on my vps and I already add push dns to my server config.

```
push "dhcp-option DNS [IP]"
```

but it doesn't work as I expected on Windows 10 using OpenVPN client. When I test using https://www.dnsleaktest.com/, it still show my ISP DNS. It works fine on Mac (tunnelblick).

Comment: It only works if you spell it correctly, i.e. `dhcp-option`

Comment: i'm sorry typo on stackexchange it's correct on my server.conf